# Trying to log in as customer with external script, then redirect to store

Tags: magento-1.9, login, customer-session

I'm working on a script that will allow me to log in as a specific customer programmatically, then redirect me to the main store page. I've tried a number of things, but none of them have worked.

The Mage file is correct and I'm not getting any exceptions. On redirect, I am simply not logged in. Removing the redirect, letting the script run and then navigating manually to the site does not keep me logged in.

Here's what I've tried:

```
require_once('../app/Mage.php');
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
Mage::app("default");
try{

Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
$customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
$customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());

$customer->loadByEmail('nsteuver@sportys.com');
$session = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");
$session->loginById($customer->getId());
$session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
}
catch(Exception $e) { echo $e; }
$url = 'http://mystore.com';
header('Location: '. $url);
```

---

```
require_once('../app/Mage.php');
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
Mage::app("default");
try{

$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId())
->loadByEmail($email);

Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer)
->renewSession();
}
catch(Exception $e) { echo $e; }
$url = 'http://mystore.com';
header('Location: '. $url);
```

---

```
require_once('../app/Mage.php');
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
Mage::app("default");
try{

function loginId($customerId)
 {
     Mage::app(); // to make sure that Mage::getModel() works
     $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
     if ($customer->getWebsiteId()) {
         Mage::init($customer->getWebsiteId(), 'website');
         $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
         $session->loginById($customerId);
         return $session;
     }
     throw new Exception('Login failed');
 }

    loginId(274660); //This is my test customer Id
}
catch(Exception $e) { echo $e; }
$url = 'http://mystore.com';
header('Location: '. $url);
```

I've tried various permutations of these, as well as replacing `Mage::app("default")` with `Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID))` and have found no difference. The behavior is exactly the same. Adding `exit()` after the redirect stops the redirect but has no effect on retaining the session, just like leaving the redirect off entirely.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?